# Wordpress - How do I check if a user is logged in?

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to show unpublished posts for some reasons for not logged in users on some parameters.
Can I configure this functionality from WP admin panel or if not, where can I change this logic in code?

Comment: Googling your title lands on http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_user_logged_in

Answer (score 2):

Use the built in function [`is_user_logged_in()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_user_logged_in) for that:

```
<?php
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
    //show the post
} else {
   //continue as normal
}
?>
```

Comment: Also make sure you add 'post_status' => 'draft' to your query
e.g.
`$args= array(
 'post_status' => 'draft',
 'paged' => $paged
);
query_posts($args);`

Comment: Ok, but in what file of WP can I fix this to show even unpublished posts for all guests?